# Seleccionar con jquery todos los elementos exceptuando un ID concreto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un html que puede contener varios input[submit] cargados dinámicamente desde varios archivos php a través de includes. El caso es que trato de que todos los botones, por defecto, queden con la propiedad disabled desde el inicio del html y hasta que el usuario no haga ciertas operaciones no se habiliten.

De momento he conseguido que o todos o ninguno queden deshabilitados, pero no logro que los desactive todos excepto uno de ellos, con ID concreto, que pertenece al menú donde el usuario puede hacer una búsqueda.

```
var $selects = $('select');
var $buttons = $('input[type="submit"]');


function checkSelect() {

  for ( var n = 0; n < $selects.length; n++ ) {
    //if value of any of the selects is empty disable buttons and return false
    if ( $($selects[n]).val() == 'nulo' ) {
      disableButtons();
      return false;
    }
  }

  enableButtons();
  return true;
}

function disableButtons() {
  for ( var n = 0; n < $buttons.length; n++ ) {
    if ($($buttons[n]).attr('id') != 'btnSearchFilter') {
      $buttons[n].attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }
}

function enableButtons() {
  $buttons.removeAttr('disabled');
}




$selects.on('change', checkSelect());
$(document).ready(checkSelect());
```

Es en la línea de **if ($($buttons[n]).attr('id') != 'btnSearchFilter') {** donde imagino que se debe poner ese filtro, pero tal cual lo tengo me da un error indicando que **$buttons[n].attr is not a function**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery tiene la expresión [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). Te adjunto una pequeña demostración de su uso:

```js
$('input:not(#uno)').each(function() {
  console.log(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="uno" type="text" value="1"/>
<input id="dos" type="text" value="12"/>
<input id="tres" type="text"value="123"/>
```

Comment: Genial !! Había leído sobre esa función hace 5 minutos, pero al haber modificado bastante código haciendo pruebas no supe dónde meterlo y al final preferí no usarlo y tratar de hacerlo con un if. Pero he deshecho todas mis modificaciones, volviendo al código inicial que los desactivaba todos, y con el :not ha sido súper fácil. Mil gracias @Pablo